# ¿Cómo usar leaftlet offline?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Leyendo la respuesta encontrada en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43608919/html-offline-map-with-local-tiles-via-leaflet descargue la aplicación Mobile Atlas Creator, cree un nuevo atlas, y descargue las fotos. Copie la carpeta en la raiz de donde tengo mi archivo index.htm, descargue los archivos leaflet.js y leaflet.css, el resultado final de este archivo es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Leaflet offline map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" href="leaflet.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="leaflet.js"></script>
        <script>
            function onLoad() {
                var latlng = L.latLng(0, 0);
                var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView(latlng, 16);

                L.tileLayer('LA_HABANA/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                {    maxZoom: 16  }).addTo(mymap);
            }
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad();"> 
        <div id="mapid" style="height: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

El problema es que me sale el grafico vacío con fondo en gris, es como si no reconociera las coordenadas, he intentado tambien con:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([50.08748, 14.42132], 16);
```

Pero nada sigue saliendo vacío. En la consola no muestra ningun error. Cómo puedo saber las coordenadas que debo introducir, fijandome en las que me muestra la aplicación Mobile Atlas Creator[image], fijarse en las señalizaciones en azul que hice, he probado poner:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([23.0720, 82.2230], 16);
```

Espero cualquier granito de arena que puedan aportarme.

El directorio de mi proyecto es el siguiente:
[image: Directorios]

**RECTIFICO** Si salen errores en la consulta:

[image: Errores]

No importa las coordenas con las que establezca el view, no decrementa el valor de la {x} donde va a buscar el archivo.

**EDITADO**: Al final jugando con los valores pasados a la función `setView` pude lograr encontrar los valores de {x} y {y} que existan en mi carpeta de fotos de los tiles del mapa. Sin tener que estar tanteando como podria saber la coordenada adecuada que me de los valores que corresponden con las imagenes?????????

Comment: Yo cree una implementación offline en angular. Lo compartí en mi github https://github.com/esteban03/offlinemap-angular-example